# How can I replace the youtube link and make it work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to make a youtube interface to play music, but I want to change the music so I've made this script. The problem is, when I change the link the video won't work anymore and it gives me an error.

```
    <iframe id="iframe" width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SHFTHDncw0g" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<input type="text" name="link" id="link" size="40">
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="changeLink();">
<script>
    function changeLink() {
        var changeLink = document.getElementById("link").value;
        document.getElementById("iframe").src += changeLink;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you adding `changeLink` to the iframe's src attribute? Shouldn't you be setting it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding a new link instead of replacing, because you used [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) instead of [`=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) in your Javascript. As a result, you have 2 links concatenated.

Try replacing:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").src += changeLink;
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").src = changeLink;
```